# What could make this record type blank?

Tags: record-type

This custom object allows a user to select two possible record type to select from.

There are few records that shows blank in the record type field.  What could case it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things I'd check:

1. When was the record created? Was it before you had record types on the object?
2. Does the user's profile who created the record have access to create objects with those record types?

Comment: In addition, if the records were loaded without a recordTypeID via data loader or some other ETL tool and the profile doing it had MASTER as the default record type it could do this.

Comment: The records were created before the two record types were created.. so you first answer probably explains it.